# Multiple values in single-value context

Tags: go, error-handling, return-value, multiple-return-values

Due to error handling in Go, I often end up with multiple values functions. So far, the way I have managed this has been very messy and I am looking for best practices to write cleaner code.

Let's say I have the following function:

```
type Item struct {
   Value int
   Name string
}

func Get(value int) (Item, error) {
  // some code

  return item, nil
}
```

How can I assign a new variable to `item.Value` elegantly. Before introducing the error handling, my function just returned `item` and I could simply do this:

```
val := Get(1).Value
```

Now I do this:

```
item, _ := Get(1)
val := item.Value
```

Isn't there a way to access directly the first returned variable?

Comment: `item` will typically be `nil` in case of an error. Without checking for an error first, your code will crash in that case.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

In case of a multi-value return function you can't refer to fields or methods of a specific value of the result when calling the function.

And if one of them is an `error`, it's there for a *reason* (which is the function *might* fail) and you should *not* bypass it because if you do, your subsequent code *might* also fail miserably (e.g. resulting in runtime panic).

However there might be situations where you *know* the code will not fail in any circumstances. In these cases you can provide a *helper* function (or method) which will discard the `error` (or raise a runtime panic if it still occurs).
This can be the case if you provide the input values for a function from code, and you know they work.
Great examples of this are the [`template`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) and [`regexp`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/) packages: if you provide a valid template or regexp at compile time, you can be sure they can always be parsed without errors at runtime. For this reason the `template` package provides the [`Must(t *Template, err error) *Template`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Must) function and the `regexp` package provides the [`MustCompile(str string) *Regexp`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#MustCompile) function: they don't return `error`s because their intended use is where the input is guaranteed to be valid.

Examples:

```
// "text" is a valid template, parsing it will not fail
var t = template.Must(template.New("name").Parse("text"))

// `^[a-z]+\[[0-9]+\]$` is a valid regexp, always compiles
var validID = regexp.MustCompile(`^[a-z]+\[[0-9]+\]$`)
```

### Back to your case

*IF* you can be certain `Get()` will not produce `error` for certain input values, you can create a helper `Must()` function which would not return the `error` but raise a runtime panic if it still occurs:

```
func Must(i Item, err error) Item {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return i
}
```

But you should not use this in all cases, just when you're sure it succeeds. Usage:

```
val := Must(Get(1)).Value
```

**Go 1.18 generics update:** Go 1.18 adds generics support, it is now possible to write a generic `Must()` function:

```
func Must[T any](v T, err error) T {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return v
}
```

This is available in [`github.com/icza/gog`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/icza/gog), as [`gog.Must()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/icza/gog#Must) (disclosure: I'm the author).

**Alternative / Simplification**

You can even simplify it further if you incorporate the `Get()` call into your helper function, let's call it `MustGet`:

```
func MustGet(value int) Item {
    i, err := Get(value)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return i
}
```

Usage:

```
val := MustGet(1).Value
```

**See some interesting / related questions:**

[How to pass multiple return values to a variadic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653779/how-to-parse-multiple-returns-in-golang/52654950#52654950)

[Return map like 'ok' in Golang on normal functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487036/return-map-like-ok-in-golang-on-normal-functions/28487270#28487270)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is.

Surprising, huh? You can get a specific value from a multiple return using a simple `mute` function:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func µ(a ...interface{}) []interface{} {
    return a
}

type A struct {
    B string
    C func()(string)
}

func main() {
    a := A {
        B:strings.TrimSpace(µ(E())[1].(string)),
        C:µ(G())[0].(func()(string)),
    }

    fmt.Printf ("%s says %s\n", a.B, a.C())
}

func E() (bool, string) {
    return false, "F"
}

func G() (func()(string), bool) {
    return func() string { return "Hello" }, true
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/IwqmoKwVm-

Notice how you select the value number just like you would from a slice/array and then the type to get the actual value.

You can read more about the science behind that from [this article](http://blog.vladimirvivien.com/2014/03/hacking-go-filter-values-from-multi.html). Credits to the author.

Answer (score 7):

No, but that is a good thing since you should always handle your errors.

There are techniques that you can employ to defer error handling, see [Errors are values](http://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values) by Rob Pike.

> ```
> ew := &errWriter{w: fd}
> ew.write(p0[a:b])
> ew.write(p1[c:d])
> ew.write(p2[e:f])
> // and so on
> if ew.err != nil {
>     return ew.err
> }
> ```

In this example from the blog post he illustrates how you could create an `errWriter` type that defers error handling till you are done calling `write`.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot directly access the first value.

I suppose a hack for this would be to return an array of values instead of "item" and "err", and then just do
    `item, _ := Get(1)[0]`
but I would not recommend this.

Answer (score 3):

How about this way?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "errors"
)

type Item struct {
    Value int
    Name string
}

var items []Item = []Item{{Value:0, Name:"zero"}, 
                        {Value:1, Name:"one"}, 
                        {Value:2, Name:"two"}}

func main() {
    var err error
    v := Get(3, &err).Value
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(v)

}

func Get(value int, err *error) Item {
    if value > (len(items) - 1) {
        *err = errors.New("error")
        return Item{}
    } else {
        return items[value]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic helper function with assumption checking:

```
func assumeNoError(value interface{}, err error) interface{} {
    if err != nil {
        panic("error encountered when none assumed:" + err.Error())
    }
    return value
}
```

Since this returns as an `interface{}`, you'll generally need to cast it back to your function's return type.

*For example, the OP's example called `Get(1)`, which returns `(Item, error)`.*

```
item := assumeNoError(Get(1)).(Item)
```

---

The trick that makes this possible: [Multi-values returned from one function call can be passed in as multi-variable arguments to another function.](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)

> As a special case, if the return values of a function or method g are equal in number and individually assignable to the parameters of another function or method f, then the call f(g(parameters_of_g)) will invoke f after binding the return values of g to the parameters of f in order.

---

*This answer borrows heavily from existing answers, but none had provided a simple, generic solution of this form.*