# Return map like 'ok' in Golang on normal functions

Tags: go, return-value, multiple-return-values

In Go, the following works (note one use of the map has one return, the other has two returns)

```
package main

import "fmt"

var someMap = map[string]string { "some key": "hello" }

func main() {
    if value, ok := someMap["some key"]; ok {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }

    value := someMap["some key"]
    fmt.Println(value)
}
```

However, I have no idea how to do this same thing with my own function. Is it possible to have similar behavior with an optional return like `map`?

For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Hello() (string, bool) {
    return "hello", true
}

func main() {
    if value, ok := Hello(); ok {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }

    value := Hello()
    fmt.Println(value)
}
```

Wont compile (due to the error `multiple-value Hello() in single-value context`) ... is there a way to make this syntax work for the function `Hello()`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`map` is different because it is a built-in *type* and not a function. The 2 forms of accessing an element of a `map` is specified by the [Go Language Specification: Index Expressions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) and backed by the compiler.

With functions you can't do this. If a function has 2 return values, you have to "expect" both of them or none at all.

However you are allowed to assign any of the return values to the [Blank identifier](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier):

```
s, b := Hello()    // Storing both of the return values

s2, _ := Hello()   // Storing only the first

_, b3 := Hello()   // Storing only the second
```

You can also choose not to store any of the return values:

```
Hello()            // Just executing it, but storing none of the return values
```

Note: you could also assign both of the return values to the blank identifier, although it has no use (other than validating that it has exactly 2 return values):

```
_, _ = Hello()     // Storing none of the return values; note the = instead of :=
```

You can also try these on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/W1st5rEi0Z).

**Helper function**

If you use it many times and you don't want to use the blank identifier, create a helper function which discards the 2nd return value:

```
func Hello2() string {
    s, _ := Hello()
    return s
}
```

And now you can do:

```
value := Hello2()
fmt.Println(value)
```

**Go 1.18 generics update:** Go 1.18 adds generics support, it is now possible to write a generic `First()` function which discards the second (or any further) return values:

```
func First[T any](first T, _ ...any) T {
    return first
}
```

This is available in [`github.com/icza/gog`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/icza/gog), as [`gog.First()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/icza/gog#First) (disclosure: I'm the author).

Using it:

```
value := First(Hello())
fmt.Println(value)
```

Comment: I had suspected as much, but wasn't sure as I had trouble googling for the docs / a definitive answer. Thanks for the reference to the docs as well!