# Can I use single variable for method that returns 2 parameters

Tags: go

I have a simple question - can I use **single value assignment** while method **returns 2 values** (val and error)?

```
resp := http.Get("http://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return map like 'ok' in golang on normal functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487036/return-map-like-ok-in-golang-on-normal-functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of operands on the left side of the assignment must match the number of values returned by the function.

You can use the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) to ignore a return value:

```
resp, _ := http.Get("http://www.google.com/")
```

It's bad practice to ignore errors like this.

Comment: Keep in mind that it's not good to ignore errors like that 

Answer (score 1):

From Go language specification :

> A tuple assignment assigns the individual elements of a multi-valued
>   operation to a list of variables. There are two forms. In the first,
>   the right hand operand is a single multi-valued expression such as a
>   function call, a channel or map operation, or a type assertion. **The
>   number of operands on the left hand side must match the number of
>   values.**

```
For instance, if f is a function returning two values, 
x, y = f() assigns the first value to x and the second to y.
```

> The blank identifier provides a way to ignore right-hand side values
>   in an assignment:

```
_ = x       // evaluate x but ignore it
x, _ = f()  // evaluate f() but ignore second result value
```