# Get nth return value from function in Go

Tags: go

I have started learning Go yesterday and so far I am fascinated. But I bumped to a problem.

Lets assume that function returns multiple vars (awesome feature).  How should I use only nth value and not first n-1 values? In example I just want to check whether key exists in hash map but do nothing with value.

```
var value, hasElement = myMap[key]
```

The error I get is

```
main.go:15: value declared and not used
```

If I just print value it will all be fine but that is not good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go: multiple value in single-value context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227095/go-multiple-value-in-single-value-context) and [Return map like 'ok' in Golang on normal functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487036/return-map-like-ok-in-golang-on-normal-functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Go, the character `_` is a placeholder indicating that you don't care about the value. Therefore, you can do

```
var _, hasElement = myMap[key]
```

which will ignore the first return value.

This extends to functions with any number of return values:

```
var a, _, _, d, e, _ = bigFunction()
```

Comment: Thanks mate! This language keeps fascinating me.

Comment: The first snippet is invalid Go code. Replace `map` with some other variable name.