# how to display only one output from multiple-value result in golang

Tags: function, go, return-value

Recently, I studied that Golang can return multiple result for a function. So I write a function:

```
func store(x, y int) (int, int) {
    return x + y, x - y
}
```

After this I write the following code:

```
func main() {
    a, b := store(6, 4)
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

And, the result is:

> 10 2

This is working fine.

But if I want to **print only a**, then how can I do this?

```
func main() {
    a, b := store(6, 4)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Result:

> tmp/sandbox683412938/main.go:12:19: b declared and not used

Also, why I can't write:

```
func main() {
    a := store(6, 4) // ???
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Please, guide me.

Comment: See related / possible duplicates: [Return map like 'ok' in Golang on normal functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487036/return-map-like-ok-in-golang-on-normal-functions/28487270#28487270); and [Go: multiple value in single-value context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227095/go-multiple-value-in-single-value-context/28233172#28233172).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use underscore placeholder (blank identifier) like this:

```
a, _ := store(6, 4)
fmt.Println(a)
```

Output:

> 10

Here's the complete example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func store(x, y int) (int, int) {
    return x + y, x - y
}

func main() {
    a, _ := store(6, 4)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Live example: https://play.golang.org/p/Z366BhtRA0

Comment: sure. Thanks a lot