# Can I make an optional return value in golang?

Tags: go

There are expressions such as:

- getting from a map (value, pres)
- asserting a type (typed value, ok)

Where there are multiple values returned, but they can be assigned to a single value context, with unsuccessful conditions causing a panic instead.

Can I make my own function work like that, allowing it to be used in a single value context and panicking on errors?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: @Atreyagaurav I am not sure if that has changed now, but at the time of me asking the answer was no. That was not a behavior you could write yourself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487036/return-map-like-ok-in-golang-on-normal-functions

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I was really curious because i had never seen such return in any other language.