# Does index expression in Go change its return type based on context?

Tags: dictionary, go, indexing, abstract-syntax-tree

> if the map contains an entry with key x, a[x] is the map element with key x and the type of a[x] is the element type of M

but

> An index expression on a map a of type map[K]V used in an assignment
>   or initialization of the special form
>
> `v, ok := a[x]`
>
> yields an additional
>   untyped boolean value.

I am still learning Go. Is it a "syntax feature" that is baked into a language and "just works when this syntax is used", i.e. calls to `v := a[x]` and `v, ok := a[x]` are represented as different types of nodes in AST like `MapGetAndCheckExistsNode(m, k, v, ok)` vs `MapGet(m, k, v)`? Or this is implemented using "normal" Go syntax and indexing function is somehow aware of whether it's output is later "destructured" or not? Is it possible to force index expression to return tuple or struct with `s.v` and `s.ok` fields using `s := a[x]` syntax?

Comment: This is a "special form" of assignment or initialization suported by only some Go expressions, it's usually refered to as "comma-ok idiom". Besides map indexing, the comma-ok is supported also by type assertions and channel receives.

Comment: Thanks, @mkopriva ! So it is a language-level syntax feature, correct? I.e. its behavior comes from the way compiler works, not from the way indexing function is implemented? I.e. one can not implement their own "special syntax for case X that treats `a, b, c := func()` and `a := func()` differently"?

Comment: Correct, you cannot implement this special form for your own functions. Your functions will always return *all* their return arguments. The most you can do is to drop some return values into the blank identifier `_`. E.g. `a, _, _ := func()`.

Comment: @mkopriva ok, great, my question was mostly if that is a syntax feature or is implemented using the language itself. Is there any consistent rule that might let you know when this syntax is applicable?

Comment: No rule, I don't know of any. In my first comment I mention the other two cases where you can use comma-ok. To confirm my claim you can go to https://golang.org/ref/spec and do ctrl+f for `, ok`.

Comment: See related / possible duplicate: [Return map like 'ok' in Golang on normal functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487036/return-map-like-ok-in-golang-on-normal-functions/28487270#28487270).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s an arbitrary rule as part of the language itself. It is used to avoid panics on typecasts:

```
t, ok := x.(T)
```

Or to check if a key really exists in a map:

```
v, ok := m[k]
```

Or to check a receive worked:

```
x, ok := <-ch
```

It’s not possible to do it with your own functions, only in these special cases inserted by the language designers. See the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) for more.