# How to pass multiple return values to a variadic function?

Tags: go, return-value, variadic, multiple-return-values

I have a Go function which returns two integer values. Below is the function

```
func temp() (int, int){
 return 1,1
}
```

Is it possible to put `temp` function directly into a `Println` and print both the outputs using string formatting as below:

```
fmt.Println("first= %d and second = %d", temp() ) // This doesn't work
```

In Python, I am able to do the following:

```
def func():
    return 1,1
print("{0}={1}".format(*func())
>> '1=2'
```

Can I do Something similar in Go too?

Comment: @maerics, i think asking a basic question for which we can find ready answers can be downvoted. But, i did search for quite sometime and i couldn't find an answer to what i was looking and so, i wrote a question. i do agree with your opinion. and thanks for the answer.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear, statically typed? i am sorry but, we can declare a:=1 or a:="Hello" right?

Comment: OR, but not both. := is just syntactic sugar for the compiler to infer the type assigned.

Comment: Eh, I don't think "multi-value expression destructuring" has anything to do with static typing. But I suppose what's obvious to one person isn't always obvious to someone else, especially neophytes...

Comment: @RayfenWindspear, thanks. understood

Comment: @maerics actually, you are right because `fmt.Println(temp())` actually works in this case. It just isn't able to do the same when the entire set of args isn't directly from the one function.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear yeah, seems like it was a deliberate choice by the go language designers, not a forced requirement by the strictness of the type system. And thanks for the follow-up, I didn't know that example would work!

Comment: @maerics seems it works in the case where a function takes a variadic interface{} as well as when the types match up exactly. TIL. https://play.golang.org/p/Tbja3KNZO_W

Comment: @RayfenWindspear, nice, i think this cannot be formatted into the string, but..i can use it directly?, right

Comment: I found an in-depth article that is worthy of an answer in itself, but it's not valid to answer a question here with just a link, so I'll put it here. https://medium.com/golangspec/multi-valued-expressions-in-go-bd28ddfe1b39

Comment: It is irritating, that the page's (tab's, e.g. in Chrome) name starts with python here. The tags might be switched. Since the questions obviously belongs rather to Go than to Python

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Foreword:** I released this utility in [`github.com/icza/gox`](https://github.com/icza/gox), see [`gox.Wrap()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/icza/gox/gox#Wrap).

---

First, for what you attempt to do you should use [`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) instead of [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) as only the former expects and uses a format string.

Going forward, this isn't supported by default, because quoting from [Spec: Calls:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)

> As a special case, if the return values of a function or method `g` are equal in number and individually assignable to the parameters of another function or method `f`, then the call `f(g(parameters_of_g))` will invoke `f` after binding the return values of `g` to the parameters of `f` in order. **The call of `f` must contain no parameters other than the call of `g`, and `g` must have at least one return value.** If `f` has a final `...` parameter, it is assigned the return values of `g` that remain after assignment of regular parameters.

And `fmt.Printf()` has a signature of:

```
func Printf(format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
```

You cannot pass other parameters to `fmt.Printf()` besides a function call (the return values of the call).

Note that the signature of `fmt.Println()` is:

```
func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
```

Which means that `fmt.Println(temp())` works, and so does with any other functions that have at least one return value, because the last sentence of the quoted part allows this (*"If `f` has a final `...` parameter, it is assigned the return values of `g` that remain after assignment of regular parameters."*)

**But with a little trick we can achieve what you want with `fmt.Printf()` too.**

Note that if `temp()` would return a value of type `[]interface{}`, we could use `...` to pass it as the value of some variadic parameter.

Meaning this works:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Printf("1: %v, 2: %v\n", temp()...)
}

func temp() []interface{} { return []interface{}{1, 2} }
```

And it properly prints (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FF8GapBomzl)):

```
1: 1, 2: 2
```

So we just need a utility function that wraps the return values of any function into a `[]interface{}`, and so we can use this to pass to `fmt.Printf()`.

And it's dead-simple:

```
func wrap(vs ...interface{}) []interface{} {
    return vs
}
```

As detailed above (with `fmt.Println()`), we can pass the return values of any function that has at least 1 return value to `wrap()` as the values of its input parameters.

Now using this `wrap()` function, see the following example:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Printf("1: %v\n", wrap(oneInt())...)
    fmt.Printf("1: %v, 2: %v\n", wrap(twoInts())...)
    fmt.Printf("1: %v, 2: %v, 3: %v\n", wrap(threeStrings())...)
}

func oneInt() int { return 1 }

func twoInts() (int, int) { return 1, 2 }

func threeStrings() (string, string, string) { return "1", "2", "3" }
```

This works, and it outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/d3zMRD-VPaS)):

```
1: 1
1: 1, 2: 2
1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3
```

**For more on the topic, see related question:**

[Multiple values in single-value context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227095/multiple-values-in-single-value-context/28233172#28233172)

[Return map like 'ok' in Golang on normal functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487036/return-map-like-ok-in-golang-on-normal-functions/28487270#28487270)

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible.  You must assign all values from a multi-value expression to separate variables to use them, e.g.:

```
a, b := temp()
fmt.Println("first = %d and second = %d", a, b)
// first = 1 and second = 1
```

**[Edit]**

Interestingly, it appears that in some cases you can use multi-value expressions as function call arguments if the argument types and arity match, or for purely variadic functions ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/wXCLqg2Yzal)):

```
func oneTwo() (int, int) {
  return 1, 2
}

func incr2(x, y int) (int, int) {
  return x + 1, y + 1
}

func main() {
  incr2(oneTwo()) // OK: multi-value return and arguments match.

  fmt.Println(oneTwo()) // OK: pure variadic function.

  fmt.Printf("%d %d", oneTwo()) // ERR: mixed formal and variadic args.
}
```

Comment: This is buried in the question comments, but is valid material for being in a more prominent view. Here is an article detailing the specifics of what is and is not possible. https://medium.com/golangspec/multi-valued-expressions-in-go-bd28ddfe1b39

Answer (score 0):

I was able to print it when i did not use any string formatting as below

```
fmt.Println(temp())
```

This was only supported by `Println`, but not `printf`