# How to spread arguments as parameters

Tags: go

I have the following Golang code:

```
rows, err := common.GetAll(c, req, params, timer)
return common.GenericRowMarshal(200, rows, err)
```

I want to figure out if it's possible to do:

```
return common.GenericRowMarshal(200, common.GetAll(c, req, params, timer)...)
```

but this doesn't compile :(

> It says "not enough arguments to call..."

Anyone know if this is possible somehow?

Comment: In this special case you can't. If parameters would match with the return types exacty, you could. You could also do it if the callable function would have a final variadic parameter, see [how to parse multiple returns in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653779/how-to-parse-multiple-returns-in-golang/52654950#52654950).

Comment: The params do match the return types tho..I think you mean *all the params* of the func to be called (outer func) have to match the inner func return values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, each time a statement executes, the function value and **parameters** to the call are evaluated as usual, see [doc](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls):

> As a special case, if the return values of a function or method g are equal in number and individually assignable to the parameters of another function or method f, then the call f(g(parameters_of_g)) will invoke f after binding the return values of g to the parameters of f in order. **The call of f must contain no parameters other than the call of g, and g must have at least one return value**. If f has a final ... parameter, it is assigned the return values of g that remain after assignment of regular parameters.

```
func Split(s string, pos int) (string, string) {
    return s[0:pos], s[pos:]
}

func Join(s, t string) string {
    return s + t
}

if Join(Split(value, len(value)/2)) != value {
    log.Panic("test fails")
}
```

---

> If f has a final `...` parameter, it is assigned the return values of g that remain after assignment of regular parameters.

For example, the following code works:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    f(200, g())
}
func f(i int, slice ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(i, slice) // 200 [[1 <nil>]]
}
func g() []interface{} {
    return []interface{}{1, nil}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've tried this too, thinking it might work. Currently (Go 1.13) you can only do this if the inner func returns exactly the parameters that the outer function expects.