# How to add new elements of a slice automatically to function parameter as slice grows

Tags: go, slice

Is there a way to doing this automatically ?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a []string
    a = append(a, "this", "this2", "this3")
    increaseArguments(a)
    a = append(a, "this4")
    increaseArguments(a)

}

func increaseArguments(b []string) {
    // I want, when i add new element to slice i want this function act as this
    // fmt.Println(b[0],b[1], b[2], b[3])

    fmt.Println(b[0], b[1], b[2])

}
```

Instead of adding b[3] as argument to fmt.Println is there a way to add it automatically ?

Comment: just looping it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if `b` would be of type `[]any`, you could pass it as the value of the variadic parameter of [`fmt.Println()`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Println):

```
fmt.Println(b...)
```

But since `b` is of type `[]string`, you can't.

But if you transform `b` into a `[]any` slice, you can. You can use this helper function to do it:

```
func convert[T any](x []T) []any {
    r := make([]any, len(x))
    for i, v := range x {
        r[i] = v
    }
    return r
}
```

And then:

```
func increaseArguments(b []string) {
    fmt.Println(convert(b)...)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ivX-cknEmXc)):

```
this this2 this3
this this2 this3 this4
```

Note: creating a new slice in `convert()` will not make this solution any slower, because passing values explicitly (like `fmt.Println(b[0], b[1], b[2])`) also implicitly creates a slice.

See related question: [How to pass multiple return values to a variadic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653779/how-to-pass-multiple-return-values-to-a-variadic-function)