# multiple-value strconv.ParseInt() in single-value context

Tags: parsing, go, type-conversion

I have the following code:

```
var i2 uint64;
var err error;
i2, err = uint64(strconv.ParseInt(scanner.Text(), 64, 64));
```

And I received the error:

```
multiple-value strconv.ParseInt() in single-value context
```

According to everything I found on the Internet, this means that I am ignoring the two parameters returned by ParseInt, but I am using err.
I know that maybe the mistake is very stupid, but I just started to learn Go and this confused me a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression `uint64(...)` is a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), and it cannot have multiple arguments (operands), but since [`strconv.ParseInt()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt) has 2 return values, you're basically passing both to the type conversion, which is not valid.

Instead do this:

```
i, err := strconv.ParseInt(scanner.Text(), 64, 64)
// Check err
i2 := uint64(i)
```

Note that the base cannot be greater than `36`, so you'll definitely get an error as you're passing `64` as the base.

Or use [`strconv.ParseUint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseUint) which will return you an `uint` value right away:

```
i, err := strconv.ParseUint(scanner.Text(), 16, 64)
// i is of type uint64, and ready to be used if err is nil
```

(Here I used a valid, `16` base. Use whatever you have to.)

Also see related question+answer: [Go: multiple value in single-value context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227095/go-multiple-value-in-single-value-context/28233172#28233172)

Answer (score 3):

> multiple-value strconv.ParseInt() in single-value context

`ParseInt` returns 2 values: integer and error. So you cannot use them in function argument where only one value allowed. You may first get `value` and `error` then use `value` in next operations.