# How to fix multiple value for single value context error in Golang?

Tags: go

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Enter a number: ")
    var addendOne int = fmt.Scan()
    fmt.Println("Enter another number: ")
    var addendTwo int = fmt.Scan()
    sum := addendOne + addendTwo
    fmt.Println(addendOne, " + ", addendTwo, " = ", sum)
}
```

This raises an error:

> multiple values in single-value context.

Why does it happen and how do we fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple-value strconv.ParseInt() in single-value context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138003/multiple-value-strconv-parseint-in-single-value-context)

Comment: There are dozens of questions on SO about "multiple values in single-value context" errors, all of which have basically the same answers. Please take a quick search of SO and see if you can find your answer.

Comment: @Adrian I am only a beginner at Golang and I can't understand any of the code in the first place.

Comment: Consider taking the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) which does an excellent job of explaining the basic concepts and syntax of the language.

Answer (score 7):

`fmt.Scan` returns two values, and you're only catching one into `addedOne`.
you should catch the error as well like this:

```
addendTwo, err := fmt.Scan() 
if err != nil {
  // handle error here
}
```

if you want to ignore the error value (not recommended!), do it like this:

```
addendTwo, _ := fmt.Scan()
```

Answer (score 2):

`fmt.Scan()` returns two values and your code expects just one when you call it.

The Scan signature `func Scan(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)` returns first the number of scanned items and eventually an error. A nil value in the error position indicates that there was no error.

Change your code like this:

```
addendOne, err := fmt.Scan()
if err != nil {
    //Check your error here
}

fmt.Println("Enter another number: ")
addendTwo, err := fmt.Scan()
if err != nil {
    //Check your error here
}
```

If you really want to ignore the errors you can used the blank identifier `_`:

```
addendOne, _ := fmt.Scan()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Scan returns int and error so you should use the := syntax that is shorthand for declaring and initializing.

```
addendOne, err := fmt.Scan()
addendTwo, err := fmt.Scan()
```

From golang fmt documentation:

> func [Scan](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scan)(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)

Answer (score 0):

I use follow way in beego v2, it works

```
    //receive tag list in post
tags := make([]string, 0, 3)
inputValues, _ := c.Input()
for k, v := range inputValues {
    if k == "tags[]" {
        tags = append(tags, v...)
    }
}
```

then you will get the result in var tags