# Debug go data struct first day using

Tags: go

I have the `eclipse software ready to go`.

What I am looking for is to debug output the return data for calling `search.RetrieveFeeds()`.

**So, in essence, I'd be able to see an array of Feed structs so i know it processed the json data file**

When I execute I get this error:

`main\main.go:10:38: multiple-value search.RetrieveFeeds() in single-value context`

I looked here: [Multiple values in single-value context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227095/multiple-values-in-single-value-context) but it was a bit over my head.

Here is what I have so far as my architecture:

**Data Json File Path**

```
src/data/data.json
```

**Data for Json File**

```
[
    {
        "site": "npr",
        "link": "http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001",
        "type": "rss"
    },
    {
        "site": "cnn",
        "link": "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_world.rss",
        "type": "rss"
    },
    {
        "site": "foxnews",
        "link": "http://feeds.foxnews.com/foxnews/world?format=xml",
        "type": "rss"
    },
    {
        "site": "nbcnews",
        "link": "http://feeds.nbcnews.com/feeds/topstories",
        "type": "rss"
    }
]
```

**Main Method File Path**

```
src/main/main.go
```

**Code for Main Method**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "search"
)

func main() {
     fmt.Println("HellAo")     
     var feeds = search.RetrieveFeeds()
     fmt.Printf("%v",feeds)
}
```

**Search File Path**

`src/search/feed.go`

**Search File Code**

```
package search

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "os"
)

const dataFile = "data/data.json"

type Feed struct {
    Name string `json:"site"`
    URI string `json:"link"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
}

func RetrieveFeeds() ([]*Feed, error){
    file, err := os.Open(dataFile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer file.Close()

    var feeds []*Feed
    err = json.NewDecoder(file).Decode(&feeds)

    return feeds, err
}
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the data json path to:

`const dataFile = "src/data/data.json"`

And now the debug dump says:

`<nil>`

Comment: `var feeds, _ = search.RetrieveFeeds()`. Even better `var feeds, err = search.RetrieveFeeds(); if err != nil { ...`. If a function in Go can return more than one value you need to have the same number of variables, or `_`s, on the LHS to assign all the values not just the first one.

Comment: It might serve you well to walk through the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/). Understanding multiple returns values is pretty fundamental to using the language.

Comment: @JimB Im working through the ebook Go in Action. I'll look at that next. It seems to debug output but the contents are empty. Maybe my data file declaration isnt right?

Comment: @jkushner your RetrieveFeeds code seems correct to me, make sure you check the error returned from it before you attempt to print the contents of the feeds.

Comment: Here it says: open data.json: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @jkushner That's pretty clear then. Make sure the path to the file is correct, and if you use relative paths make sure the program is executed from that directory from which the relative path correctly loactes the file you want to open.

Comment: Got it thanks a lot!

Comment: You do not need a debugger when your program is not running. You must fix the compiler errors first.