# Throwing away error value on string to int conversion

Tags: go, type-conversion

I have a Go program that I simply want to convert a string to an int. I understand the function:

```
val, err := strconv.Atoi(myValueAsAString)
```

works and I can check the error by the following:

```
if err != nil {
    //handle error
}
```

But what if I am 100% the string will be a number, and I want to convert it to an int in an if statement, like the following:

```
if 45 + strconv.Atoi(value) >= 90 {
    //do something
}
```

But strconv.Atoi also returns an error value as well, so how can I throw that away and essentially do what I did above, without having to define the variable above the if statement and use it in the if statement. I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but I would love to know.

Comment: See possible duplicate [Multiple values in single-value context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227095/multiple-values-in-single-value-context/28233172#28233172).

Comment: @icza That question was simply asking how to convert string to an int. I already knew how to do that, what I wanted was to do it in an if statement and throw away the error.

Comment: On the general principle that errors you are sure won't happen, actually will happen, I'd use a `mustXXX` wrapper function that panics if the error that cannot happen, does happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Create a wrapper function that discards the error result:

```golang
func atoi(s string) int {
    value, _ := strconv.Atoi(s)
    return value
}
```

```golang
if 45 + atoi(value) >= 90 {
    //do something
}
```

2. Or, do the conversion as a statement before the `if` and ignore the error result:

```golang
if i, _ := strconv.Atoi(value); 45 + i >= 90 {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I would argue the second option is more idiomatic Go.

Comment: @EmilePels: In Go, don't ignore errors. Neither answer is idiomatic. Quite the contrary. Both answers are bad.

Answer (score 2):

> I simply want to convert a string to an int.
>
> What if I am 100% the string will be a number.
>
> I want to convert a string of numeric digits to an int in an if
>   statement, like the following:
>
> ```
> if 45 + strconv.Atoi(value) >= 90 {
>     //do something
> }
> ```

---

What if you are wrong?

---

Write a simple Go wrapper function for `strconv.Atoi`. In Go, don't ignore errors.

```
// ASCII digits to integer.
func dtoi(s string) int {
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return i
}
```

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

// ASCII digits to integer.
func dtoi(s string) int {
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return i
}

func main() {
    value := "1024"
    if 45+dtoi(value) >= 90 {
        fmt.Println("do something")
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/I3plKW2TGSZ

Output:

```
do something
```