# How do you append function result, while overwriting error?

Tags: function, go

Usually, `result, err := func()` is used.

When one of the variables is already initialized:

```golang
_, err := func()

var result string
result, err = func()
```

Doing:

```
result, err = func()
all_results += result // seems redundant and unneeded
```

How do you append results to one of them (result), and reset the other one?

```golang
// along the lines of this:
var result slice
// for loop {
result, _ += func() // combine this line
_, err = func() // with this line
```

Can you do:

```golang
result +=, err = func()
// or
result, err +=, = func()
// or
result, err += = func()
// or
result, err (+=, =) func() // ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language spec does not support different treatment for multiple return values.

However, it's very easy to do it with a helper function:

```
func foo() (int, error) {
    return 1, nil
}

func main() {
    var all int

    add := func(result int, err error) error {
        all += result
        return err
    }

    if err := add(foo()); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := add(foo()); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := add(foo()); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(all)
}
```

This will output `3` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_yVgxOqo5h9)).

If you can move the error handling into the helper function, it can also look like this:

```
var all int

check := func(result int, err error) int {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return result
}

all += check(foo())
all += check(foo())
all += check(foo())

fmt.Println(all)
```

This outputs the same, try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nMdNkoRXNaK).

Another variant can be to do everything in the helper function:

```
var all int

handle := func(result int, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    all += result
}

handle(foo())
handle(foo())
handle(foo())

fmt.Println(all)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PDCbKazG1oa).

See related: [Multiple values in single-value context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227095/multiple-values-in-single-value-context/28233172#28233172)

Comment: Could you gather the errors instead / as well; and handle them at once (one `if != nil`, outside of a `for`)?

Comment: @u15p7fgy863eiq5 You can of course do anything. One option is to store the error in a variable, which is checked by the helper function. If there was a previous error, the helper function can be a no-op.

Comment: would you think multi-operator short variable definitions would be useful enough as a feature to propose to golang?

Comment: @u15p7fgy863eiq5 I don't think it's needed, but that's just my opinion.